# Firebase Auth for Android: createUserWithEmailAndPassword is working late

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've written a correctly code using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` for `Android`.
I've written the static final integer constants for account create is successful or not successful (that email is already used):

```
public static final int SUCCESSFUL = 100;
public static final int EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_USED = 101;
```

There is a method to create a new account:

```
public static int createAnAccount(String email, String password, final Context ctx) {
  final int[] res = new int[1];
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // User has registered successfully...
            res[0] = SUCCESSFUL;
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "First has worked - Registered!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else {
            try {
              throw task.getException();
            } catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
              // That email address is already used...
              res[0] = EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_USED;
              Toast.makeText(ctx, "First has worked - This email is already used!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              // Undefined error...
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
      });
  Toast.makeText(ctx, "Second has worked - Value of res[0] = " + res[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return res[0];
}
```

I wanted to catch that the user has registered successfully or the email is already used. For this I wanted to return `SUCCESSFUL` if `task.isSuccessful()` is `true`, return `EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_USED` if `task.isSuccessful()` is `false` but, I couldn't return the values from `onComplete()` method because is a `anonymous inner class method`. So, I used `res` integer array. Value of `res` is `SUCCESSFUL` if `isSuccessful() is true` or is `EMAIL_IS_ALREADY_USED` if `isSuccessful() is false`.

It is always working correctly if any user has registered or has used an already registered email. I have to see first `First has worked - bla bla bla` message and then `Second has worked - Value of res[0] = bla bla` message. But first has worked `Second has worked - ...` message and then `First has worked - ...` message. I know the problem. The problem is about that `Second has worked` toast message and `return res[0]` are working before `onComplete()` method. I mean, `return res[0]` working before value of `res[0]` isn't given in `onComplete`.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Did you try to implement onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: Yes, I tried now, but it's not working. As far as I know [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener#public-methods) says that `onAuthStateChanged` gets invoked only signed in, signed out and user changes.